# Ruby set an argument variable in an object

Tags: ruby, json

I need a quick hack for a ruby script which parse a json file for some variables. It stores in #{name} the name string from the json file where the id is the input for the argument.

The issue is that I cannot set the ID argument which is `#{b}` in the object data-on_day_you_want. If I put it in `"#{b}"` it won't match with the value from the json file.If I hardcoded it with 281 it works perfectly. 
ps:Please find below the a small part from the json.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

a, b = ARGV          #(environment and ID arguments)
file = File.read('file.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
data_on_day_you_want = data_hash["tenantAuthzProfiles"].detect{ |h| h["id"] == #{b} }   # HERE IS THE ISSUE 
name = data_on_day_you_want["name"]

puts "NAME is: #{name}"
```

the json:

```
{
    "name": "Production Environment",
    "roles": ["Host Admin"],
    "id": 281
}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to parse `b` as integer:

```
data_on_day_you_want = data_hash["tenantAuthzProfiles"].detect do |h| 
  h["id"] == b.to_i
end
```

In your code, `b` receives the value `"281"` which is a string. When you compare string to integer, it'll always be false:

```
"281" == 281
# => false
```

The [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) method parses the string, and returns the integer value it represents:

```
"281".to_i == 281
# => true
```

(note that, contrary to other languages' parse methods, `to_i` is *very* lenient, so you might get surprising results `"surprise".to_i == 0`)

The notation of `#{}` is relevant to [String interpolation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation), and is only valid inside a string (surrounded by double-quoutes)

Comment: yes, but I want the value that I gave to the script as an argument there. Like in the example below: ./script.rb environment 281 ...where 281 is the id value.  b.to_i is not working it's showing me the same name value even if I change the number... The main priblem is that I cannot set #{b} properly to be read as a variable

Comment: Sorry mate, your solution it's working...I was testing it on the wrong json :D  ...If you have a link or an explination why is this working and why is b.to_i knows about my input , it would be great. Thanks again

Comment: @VladCenan - I've updated the answer with some more details and explanations

Comment: Thanks again, this will be very useful on my ruby journey.

Comment: If this answered your question - feel free to accept it